# How to write a personal statement for a "PhD orientation program" (in mathematics)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, writing, statement-of-purpose

I'm about to apply for a short "**visiting and orientation program**" at a large prestigious university where I may be interested in applying for graduate school.

> This program lasts a couple of weeks and consists of
>
> - several courses that present the research done by every research group in the math department;
> - meetings with the faculty members and current students.

For the admission, I'm required to submit a **statement of purpose**.

Now, the scope of statements of purpose written for graduate admission is quite clear: they need to show research potential and experience in an area of interest.

However, I'm confused about what makes a good candidate for a PhD "visiting and orientation program".

> That is, what kind of **information**, **qualification**, and **motivations** may admission committees be looking for in a candidate for such a program?

Comment: Can you say what country this is in? I've never heard of such a program in the US.

Answer (score 1):

I speculate as I do not know the faculty and their philosophy. 
To my own experiences (PhD 20 years ago, and had some DBA students on my own before I went back to industry), I would suggest you differentiate between research potential and experience against "visiting and orientation". For an orientation program, ...

- I would expect people to be open to all directions of learning, in our own as well as in different areas.
- The ability to network,
- ability for out-of-the box thinking,
- ability for telling ideas but also listening.

Think about onion rings around the exploration of your topics.

How do you show those abilities? Examples from your life?